# Get Textbox Value in New Page in Sitecore MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore-mvc

I am using Sitecore 7.1. I created one search page and created a textbox by using the Web Form For marketer in it. On button click I want catch the text box value in a new page name search-result. How can I catch the WFFFM text box value in New page? I Don't want use JavaScript click event and query string.

```
<form class="search-form" action="/searchresults" method='get' > 
    <label><input type="text" name="searchText" id="searchText" placeholder="@placeholderText"></label> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" class="@cssClass"> 
</form>
```

But i am getting below type of URL 
  http://www.xyz/searchresults?searchText=searchTextHere&submit=

Comment: When I understand your question correctly you want to have a textbox (e.g. in the top-right corner) and want to go to a different search page where you want to search by the entered text?  You could either directly post to the search page or make a post to the current page and redirect with a query string parameter. But why would you use WFFM for this search box? Or did I missunderstand your question?

Comment: Thanks Yan for your comment . I am using Html Control for search box in MVC Razor. I am able to go to page by JavaScript with search text in Query strung but i want avoid query string

Comment: Using query string for redirecting to search page within a search box if best practice, why do you want to avoid it? As I already mentioned you could also directly post to the search page. Please show us the code you already have so we can better help you...

Comment: as you suggested i applied given changes. But is show one query string with url

Comment: if you want to get rid of the submit parameter in the query string, you can remove the name attribute from the button.

Answer (score 0):

Can you capture the "onsubmit" event and update the URL to whatever you need using Javascript? You only said not to use onclick event.   I'm assuming that you may want to have /searchresults/ as a result.  Of course, I assume that your routes are set for this and searchresults can process this correctly.